# How to delete a specific lesson progress in R swirl package? Is there a command or a function that can do this?

Tags: swirl

Suppose I have installed a course "X" from swirl in R. This course X has lessons X1, X2, X3, and so on. How do I delete my progress in a particular lesson I am in, let's say X2?

What I tried:
Normally, most courses will ask you to type something in r-prompt for an answer. So if I typed `restart()` in r-prompt, it would restart the lesson, but this lesson does not provide access to r-prompt. It has only multiple choice selections.

So I tried `delete_progress("MyUserName")` and it deleted all my courses history! I only want to delete history of one lesson, not even a course.

I went to R directory and then library/swirl/user_data/ and found a folder with my username there. This folder had a list of files, one for each lesson I completed. I manually deleted the file corresponding the lesson, say X2, and it worked. When I went back to swirl, the lesson started from the beginning.

However, I am not satisfied with this workaround. Is there a direct way using a command line interface or a swirl function that could delete progress of a lesson?

I am using Windows 10, if that is of any relevance.

Thanks.